# Space between hrefs

Tags: html, css

I have this div.

```
 <div class="abc">
    <a href="#">Select All</a>
     <a href="#">#</a>
    {{#each letters}}
        <a href="#">{{this}}</a>
    {{/each}}
 </div>
```

Which prints something like this:
[image]

But I want to get something like this:
[image]

Ignore the star icon.

I want to have space between each letter and also change the color of the href

Already tried with

```
margin-left: 1.375rem;
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `display: inline-block;` in `<a>` and set your `margin` or `padding`

**CSS**

```
a{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px; //Adjust your needs
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/a3L6pqLg/2/)**

Comment: Thumbs up from me, Explain little bit display property for the OP education. @carloss please read http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp for details

Comment: @saqibahmad hi saq yea i know the question is kinda "silly" but i really get stuck on this one and have to come here like the big newe im btw thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Use padding:

```
<a href="#" style="padding:3px">{{this}}</a>
```

Of course, it would be a lot cleaner to use a css class.